# How to expand and collapse a div made using aria-expanded attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, dom-events

I am basically trying to write a script that could expand a collapsed `<div>` using JavaScript. While using the frontend part, I can collapse and expand that `<div>` just by clicking on that but when it comes to JavaScript, it's not working if I try `element.click()` or even `element.ariaExpanded = "true"`.

I am attaching the code for before and after click on that `<div>` highlighting the differences in the code.

[image: Before Clicking on <div> Element in Frontend]

[image: After Clicking on <div> Element in Frontend]

I tried several things including

```
var outerDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("section--section--BukKG");
outerDiv[0].ariaExpanded = "true";
outerDiv[0].children[0].ariaExpanded = "true";
outerDiv[0].click();
document.querySelectorAll('.section--section-chevron--tJ4mD')[0].classList.remove('udi-angle-down');
document.querySelectorAll('.section--section-chevron--tJ4mD')[0].classList.add('udi-angle-up');
```

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/ariaExpanded) `"The ariaExpanded property of the Element interface reflects the value of the aria-expanded attribute, which indicates whether a grouping element owned or controlled by this element is expanded or collapsed."` - I don't believe this modifies the state of the element itself though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you did not include any HTML markup the following is a rough facsimile of the original. You are essentially trying to toggle the visibility of the DIV elements and indicate, using ARIA tags, that the element is or is not `expanded`

To that end you can make use of the `aria-expanded` attribute in CSS to govern the visibility of the child objects within the parent container. By setting the attribute `aria-expanded` as either true or false will then invoke the relevant css rule to display/hide the children.

```js
const bool=(v)=>v=='true' ? true : false;

const clickhandler=function(e){
  this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', !bool(this.ariaExpanded) )
}

document.querySelectorAll('div.section--section--bukkg').forEach(div=>div.addEventListener('click',clickhandler) );
```

```css
.section--section--bukkg{
  transition:ease-in-out 250ms all;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:1rem;
  margin:1rem;
}

[aria-expanded="false"] .section--section--heading{
  display:none;
}
[aria-expanded="true"] .section--section--heading{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class='section--section--bukkg' data-purpose='section-panel' aria-expanded='false'>
  <div class='section--section--heading' role='button' tabindex=0 data-purpose='section-heading'>
    <div class='section-title' data-purpose='section-panel'>A title of some sort 1</div>
    <span class='section-chevron'>Some content in a SPAN 1</span>
    <div class='font-text-xs'>teeney weeney text 1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='section--section--bukkg' data-purpose='section-panel' aria-expanded='false'>
  <div class='section--section--heading' role='button' tabindex=1 data-purpose='section-heading'>
    <div class='section-title' data-purpose='section-panel'>A title of some sort 2</div>
    <span class='section-chevron'>Some content in a SPAN 2</span>
    <div class='font-text-xs'>teeney weeney text 2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='section--section--bukkg' data-purpose='section-panel' aria-expanded='false'>
  <div class='section--section--heading' role='button' tabindex=2 data-purpose='section-heading'>
    <div class='section-title' data-purpose='section-panel'>A title of some sort 3</div>
    <span class='section-chevron'>Some content in a SPAN 3</span>
    <div class='font-text-xs'>teeney weeney text 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```